# How do I query a transaction receipt and confirm that the transaction is executed successfully on Hedera network?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I have a completed transaction and I have its transaction ID. I am trying to query that transaction using the following code:

```
const transactionQueryExecuteTx = await new TransactionReceiptQuery()
            .setTransactionId(transactionId)
            .setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts)
            .setGrpcDeadline(grpcDeadline)
            .execute(this.client);
```

However, I am getting an error saying that the transaction receipt was not found, even though I can see the transaction on the Hedera network. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: please share the value of the `transactionId` variable in your sample code